# Set angular directive value inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to set values from ng-repeat to a custom directive. However unfortunately it's not setting the value inside repeater but outside of ng repeater its setting value.

HTML:

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('testController', function ($scope) {  

$scope.data = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Image Link"},
                {"id": 2, "name": "Image Upload"},
                {"id": 3, "name": "Video Link"},
                {"id": 4, "name": "Video Upload"}
];      
    
});

app.directive('heartCounterDir', ['$http', function($http) {
  
return {
 restrict: 'E',
 transclude: true,
 replace: true,     
 scope:{
  id:'=',
  name:'=',
 },
 controller:function($scope, $element, $attrs){

  $scope.heartCounterAction = function(){ 
   
   console.log($attrs.id , $attrs.name );

   };
 $scope.heartCounterAction();

 },
 
 template: '<div></div>' 
};

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  
 <body>
 <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
  <div ng-repeat="d in data">
  <div> the id is : {{d.id}} and the name is : {{d.name}}</div>
  <heart-counter-dir id="d.id" name="d.name" >
   
  </heart-counter-dir> 

  </div>
  
  
 </div>
```

in the console.log I'm getting "d.id d.name" ( the string itself ) not the value. Could please let me know how to fix this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$scope` for values not `$attr` inside directive like as

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,     
    scope:{
        id:'=',
        name:'=',
    },
    controller:function($scope, $element, $attrs){

        $scope.heartCounterAction = function(){ 

            console.log($scope.id , $scope.name );

            };
    $scope.heartCounterAction();

    },

    template: '<div></div>' 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution !

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the parameters to the scope, so why do you do `$attrs.id` and `$attrs.name` inside your directive instead of `$scope.id` and `$scope.name`?